# Optimising a Lead query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, window-functions

I'd like to select an entity based on it's name and based on alphabetical order, select the `name` of the next row. The `name` column is a varchar, is unique and has an index.

Using the [Lead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) window function this is what I've come up with:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  
        *,
        LEAD("name", 1, '') OVER(ORDER BY name) AS next
    FROM entity    
    ORDER BY "name"
) results
WHERE "name" = 'CACTUS';
```

However the query performance degrades as the size of the entity table increases.

The query plan looks like:

```
Subquery Scan on results  (cost=0.42..31205.95 rows=1 width=299)
  Filter: ((results.""name"")::text = 'CACTUS'::text)"
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..29002.24 rows=176297 width=299)"
        ->  Index Scan using ""IDX_2fbbd02c0f1ee2a4dda593705d"" on entity  (cost=0.42..26357.79 rows=176297 width=235)"
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

postgresql version 11+

Comment: `lead()` without an order by doesn't really make sense to begin with - there is no such thing as "the next row" unless you specify an `order by`. But yes it is expected that this gets slower the more rows you have, because the inner query has to sort **all** rows in the table

Comment: Ok, I assumed it would use the order of the subquery, I've updated the window function to have an explicit ORDER BY.

Answer (score 3):

You could try without a window function and a co-related scalar sub-query, but I am not sure if that really is faster:

```
SELECT e1.name, 
       (select coalesce(max(name), '')
        from entity e2
        where e2.name > e1.name) as next
FROM entity e1
WHERE e1.name = 'CACTUS';
```

Comment: Thanks, this works orders of magnitude faster for me but I had to add an `ORDER BY` to the sub-query and query. I also updated the question to reflect that I wanted an order :D. If there are no other answers in a couple days I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @shusson: but you claimed that `name` is unique, so the condition `where e1.name = 'CACTUS'` can only return a single row - I don't see why you would need an `order by` for that. The use of `max()` and `>` does impose an order on the select "next" name

Comment: yes but I'm interested in the name of the next row based on a particular order, let's say alphabetical.

Comment: @shusson: the condition `e2.name > e1.name` imposes an order

Comment: yeah ok I'll update the question to impose alphabetical order

Comment: @shusson the condition `e2.name > e1.name` imposes an alphabetical order (the same that is used with `order by name`)

Comment: First, should the inner select not be ``min(name)`` instead of max? Second, how do you get the next value, if the column is not unique.